# flexbox container inside the table container, PRE tags and managing overflow

Tags: css, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm working on very complex **DASHBOARD** using `bootstrap-4`. I found an issue with `<pre>` with `Flexbox`. Actually this isn't `flexbox` and `<pre>` issue it's `table` container issue. My `html` structure should be like this.

`table-container
    flex-container
        pre-container`

> html and css snippet

```css
.container-example{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.30);
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.code-example-body{
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -moz-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -moz-box-pack: start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.code-example{
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.normal-div{
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.long-div{
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  bottom: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/assets/css/docs.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-example">
    <div class="code-example-body">
        <div class="normal-div">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
        <div class="code-example">
            <figure class="highlight">
                <pre><code class="language-html" data-lang="html"><span class="cp">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;html</span> <span class="na">lang=</span><span class="s">"en"</span><span class="nt">&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;head&gt;</span>
<span class="c">&lt;!-- Required meta tags --&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;meta</span> <span class="na">charset=</span><span class="s">"utf-8"</span><span class="nt">&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;meta</span> <span class="na">name=</span><span class="s">"viewport"</span> <span class="na">content=</span><span class="s">"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"</span><span class="nt">&gt;</span>
<span class="c">&lt;!-- Bootstrap CSS --&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;link</span> <span class="na">rel=</span><span class="s">"stylesheet"</span> <span class="na">href=</span><span class="s">"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"</span> <span class="na">integrity=</span><span class="s">"sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ"</span> <span class="na">crossorigin=</span><span class="s">"anonymous"</span><span class="nt">&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;/head&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;body&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;h1&gt;</span>Hello, world!<span class="nt">&lt;/h1&gt;</span>
<span class="c">&lt;!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. --&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;script </span><span class="na">src=</span><span class="s">"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"</span> <span class="na">integrity=</span><span class="s">"sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n"</span> <span class="na">crossorigin=</span><span class="s">"anonymous"</span><span class="nt">&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;script </span><span class="na">src=</span><span class="s">"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"</span> <span class="na">integrity=</span><span class="s">"sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb"</span> <span class="na">crossorigin=</span><span class="s">"anonymous"</span><span class="nt">&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;script </span><span class="na">src=</span><span class="s">"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"</span> <span class="na">integrity=</span><span class="s">"sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn"</span> <span class="na">crossorigin=</span><span class="s">"anonymous"</span><span class="nt">&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;/body&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;/html&gt;</span></code></pre>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="long-div"></div>
  <div class="footer">
        I'm footer. Please set me bottom of the browser or end of the document.
    </div>
</div>
```

If I remove or replace `display: table;` form `.container-example` then it's working well. Also this issue have another solution. If I  set fixed width in `.code-example` then it's working.

`.code-example{
    flex: 0 0 400px;
    max-width: 400px;
}`

> Note: I can't remove or replace `display: table;` from parent element also I need `100%` `width` not fixed `width`.

I have absolute footer on bottom. This footer always set to end of the document or end of the browser. Footer `position` should be `absolute`. That reason I can't remove or replace `display: table;`.

> Only solution horizontal scroll bar for `pre`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Just need [fixed table mode](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout).

`.container-example{
    table-layout: fixed;
}`

> Working code snippet

```css
.container-example{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.30);
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  table-layout: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.code-example-body{
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -moz-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -moz-box-pack: start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.code-example{
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.normal-div{
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.long-div{
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  bottom: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/assets/css/docs.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-example">
    <div class="code-example-body">
        <div class="normal-div">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
        <div class="code-example">
            <figure class="highlight">
                <pre><code class="language-html" data-lang="html"><span class="cp">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;html</span> <span class="na">lang=</span><span class="s">"en"</span><span class="nt">&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;head&gt;</span>
<span class="c">&lt;!-- Required meta tags --&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;meta</span> <span class="na">charset=</span><span class="s">"utf-8"</span><span class="nt">&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;meta</span> <span class="na">name=</span><span class="s">"viewport"</span> <span class="na">content=</span><span class="s">"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"</span><span class="nt">&gt;</span>
<span class="c">&lt;!-- Bootstrap CSS --&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;link</span> <span class="na">rel=</span><span class="s">"stylesheet"</span> <span class="na">href=</span><span class="s">"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"</span> <span class="na">integrity=</span><span class="s">"sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ"</span> <span class="na">crossorigin=</span><span class="s">"anonymous"</span><span class="nt">&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;/head&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;body&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;h1&gt;</span>Hello, world!<span class="nt">&lt;/h1&gt;</span>
<span class="c">&lt;!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. --&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;script </span><span class="na">src=</span><span class="s">"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"</span> <span class="na">integrity=</span><span class="s">"sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n"</span> <span class="na">crossorigin=</span><span class="s">"anonymous"</span><span class="nt">&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;script </span><span class="na">src=</span><span class="s">"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"</span> <span class="na">integrity=</span><span class="s">"sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb"</span> <span class="na">crossorigin=</span><span class="s">"anonymous"</span><span class="nt">&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;script </span><span class="na">src=</span><span class="s">"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"</span> <span class="na">integrity=</span><span class="s">"sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn"</span> <span class="na">crossorigin=</span><span class="s">"anonymous"</span><span class="nt">&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;/body&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;/html&gt;</span></code></pre>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="long-div"></div>
  <div class="footer">
        I'm footer. Please set me bottom of the browser or end of the document.
    </div>
</div>
```